# Why my command prompt is not recognizing 'netstat' as a command

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe

I want to figure out my running ports in Windows 10, but when I write command

```
C:\> netstat
```

in the console, I get the following error

```
'netstat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

or output of echo %PATH% as and of echo %PATH EXT%

Comment: What happens off you use the command `C:\Windows\system32\netstat.exe`?

Comment: Have you checked to see whether `netstat.exe` is present? On my system, it's in `C:\Windows\System32`. Is `C:\Windows\System32` in your PATH?

Comment: @Twisty  when I did
    C:\Windows\system32\netstat.exe  it give me the result.

JeffZeitlin yes I do have 
    C:\Windows\System32  in my Path

Comment: Edit your question to include the output of `echo %PATH%` and of `echo %PATHEXT%`

Comment: Do `where netstat*` and/or `for %A in (netstat.exe) Do @Echo %~$PATH:A` return (only) the correct path?

Comment: You should run it as administrator,that is probably it. [here is a related well answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632667/how-do-i-kill-the-process-currently-using-a-port-on-localhost-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Did you mess around with the PATH variables?

Right click This PC → Properties → Advanced System Settings → Advanced tab → Environment Variables

In System variables, edit Path

Make sure that these paths are defined in the Path variable:

C:\WINDOWS\system32

C:\WINDOWS

Comment: I think you are right. 

I think the other answer missed the fact that Ameen mentioned in her Aug 2, 2017 at 19:14 comment that it worked just fine when the full path was used.  So it's definitely a %PATH% issue.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like NetStat is no longer registered. You can check by going to **My Computer - Properties - Advanced - Environment Variables - Path**. If it is not there you can add it, just make sure you use the entire path when you do.

Comment: They mentioned in their comment that it worked with the full path harcoded, so it wasn't a registration issue.